# TDD in Django, how to unit test my modelform?

Tags: django, tdd

I'm new to TDD, and trying to apply TDD practice in a Django project.

Based on London school TDD workflow, I'm working outside-in, view layer, form layer and model layer. At form layer, I plan to construct a modelform, with some
custom validation methods. I think, based on TDD, I need to only test my custom methods,
without touching:

- the whole ModelForm logic provided by Django, which is a well-tested dependency.
- the lower model layer, which does not exist yet.

But how can I do it? For example, with the following modelform:

```
from django import forms
from app import models

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.MyModel
        fields = ("field1", "field2")

    def clean_field1(self):
        # custom cleaning logic

    def clean_field2(self):
        # custom cleaning logic

    def clean(self):
        # custom cleaning logic
```

- How can I (or should I) mock `MyModel`? I've come up with

  ```
  @patch("app.forms.MyModelForm._meta.model")
  class FormTest(TestCase):
      #...
  ```

  But maybe it's a little bit insane? And I'm not sure how well the  `Mock`
  object will work with `ModelForm` internal logic. For one thing, all form
  fields are gone, aren't they?
- How can I unit test these custom methods? By setting `self.cleaned_data` manually?

Comment: Patching the unit under test certainly seems like a bad idea. But could you give a better idea of the *behaviour* you're trying to test?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hi, thanks for helping. You think `MyModel` here belongs to unit under test? Isn't it a lower level dependency (meaning form layer depends on model layer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using frameworks like django it is tricky to write unit tests. The problem is that the model and the form are very tightly coupled by django design. By coupling here I mean for example that form expects specific fields to exist in model.

Given that the model rarely has any logic itself and usually is just a definition of fields I would say that it is more practical to test the form together with the model and do not mock it. The tests for the logic you define in the form in most cases will depend only on the definition of the fields.

But back to you your question.

You can be a purist and mock the model. In order to test the form in isolation you would need to mock the model but a bit differently. Instead of using pure `Mock` you need to create another test model with a minimal definition of the model that this form can work with. This test model establishes kind of a contract between the form and the model. Namely what fields this form expects the model to have. And then in you test you should mock the model in the form with the test model.

And you can do that using regular TDD practice of incremental steps. That is start from form with a test for one field and create (initially empty) test model and add fields one by one to it along creation tests for them in the form.

Of cause you would still need an integration test (or tests) to check that your form works with the real model.

And here's one important point. You are correct that you should not test the logic provided by django. But it does not mean that your test can't rely on it and use it.

The same applies to your own code. The test for form should not test you model directly, but from practical perspective it can rely on the real model (given that model logic itself is tested as well in its own test). One would argue that this is not a pure unit test, but it is the price you pay for using [the Web framework for perfectionists with deadlines](https://www.djangoproject.com).

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you about the point that model form tests can rely on a test model. What I end up with is a strategy that when TDDing a model form, I firstly create a placeholder model for that model form to use. And only write tests for my custom validation methods. If any of my custom validation method needs data that should've been provided by django's `ModelForm` logic (such as `cleaned_data`), I provide them manually in my test case. After form layer has completed, I dive into model layer and fill in placeholder model via the same TDD workflow.