# django test client CRUD API, unit testing

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, tdd

I want to write pure unit tests for my CRUD APP in django.
Everyone use django tests or pytests, but I am really confused. Should I use test client to testing eg. POST method?
Unit tests should be isolate and class should be test independently. We should use mocks DB etc.

So why this code from https://medium.com/@ksarthak4ever/test-driven-development-tdd-in-django-and-django-rest-framework-drf-a889a8068cb7 is unit tests?

```
class PrivateIngredientsApiTest(TestCase): #Test the private ingredients api
 
 def setUp(self):
  self.client = APIClient()
  self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
   'ksarthak4ever@gmail',
   'hakunamatata'
  )
  self.client.force_authenticate(self.user)

 def test_retrieve_ingredients_list(self): #Test retrieving a list of ingredients
  Ingredient.objects.create(user=self.user, name='Potato')
  Ingredient.objects.create(user=self.user, name='Peas')
  res = self.client.get(INGREDIENTS_URL)ingredients = Ingredient.objects.all().order_by('-name')
  serializer = IngredientSerializer(ingredients, many=True)
  self.assertEqual(res.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
  self.assertEqual(res.data, serializer.data)
```

For me this is functional test, not unit test. I search all over the internet how to write unit tests for django, but I didn't find anything.

Comment: The test client _is_ a kind of a mock, and it is an easy and established way to test your Django classes. Is there a practical reason why that is a problem for your tests?

Comment: I just want to learn how to write good unit tests, not functional or integration tests

Comment: My point is, SO is about asking [concrete questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for concrete problems, otherwise your question may be closed as unfocused or opinion-based. So my advice would be to write a small Django app, and think about what would be needed to test your concrete Django view function or class. Either you'll find that you need something like the test client (which is what I would say), or you come up with some simple and clever idea to test it without this, try something out, and ask here again if it doesn't work.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763138/tdd-in-django-how-to-unit-test-my-modelform) is about django forms and models specifically but I would say the answer in it answers your question as well. At least it addresses the (im)practicalities of unit testing in django.