# How to write pure unittest in Django?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, tdd

so my question is, how to write pure unit tests with Django?

For exmaple I have this model:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, validators=[MinLengthValidator(5)])
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This serializer:

```
class TopicSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Topic
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'created_at')
```

and I wrote these tests:

```
class TopicModelTest(TestCase):

    def test_create_topic(self):
        topic = Topic(title='Topic title')
        self.assertEqual(topic.title, 'Topic title')

    def test_too_short_title(self):
        topic = Topic(title='W'*4)
        with self.assertRaises(ValidationError):
            topic.save()
            topic.full_clean()

class TopicSerializerTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self) -> None:
        
        mocked = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
        self.topic_attr = {'title': 'What is the weather like?'}
        self.topic_serialized = {'id': 1, 'title': 'What is the weather like?', 'created_at': '2020-01-01T00:00:00Z'}
        with mock.patch('django.utils.timezone.now', mock.Mock(return_value=mocked)):
            self.topic = Topic.objects.create(**self.topic_attr)
        self.serializer = TopicSerializer(instance=self.topic)

    def test_contains_expected_fields(self):
        
        data = self.serializer.data
        self.assertCountEqual(data.keys(), ['id', 'title', 'created_at'])

    def test_serialized_data(self):

        self.assertEqual(self.serializer.data, self.topic_serialized)
```

Everything works, but this is not unit tests. This is integration tests, because database is used.

So my question is, how can I write unit tests? I ask about this, because many companies want to write simple project with unit test (TDD) for junior, but I don't know how can I write isolated unit tests without DB

Comment: Django (and other framworks like flask) need a db to function, and thus have build-in support for using a test database which resides in memory only (in Django you usually use SQLite). Calling these tests unit tests is common, and if your business logic relies on Django, it also relies on an underlying datastore that cannot be mocked away with reasonable effort.

Comment: You might find this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51763138/tdd-in-django-how-to-unit-test-my-modelform/51781735#51781735 useful. That answer is about a form but the same is true for a model.